# Extract second element from a three element map in c++

Tags: c++

I am creating a map. The map works fine though. I need to extract the character for a particular index (for another computation). 
Code for map is below:

```
//site index, val type, num of val
typedef map<int, pair<char, int> > Maptype;

Maptype my_map;
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++){ //create the system 
    char Type = 's';
    int Count = 10;
    //insert to map
    my_map.insert( make_pair( i, make_pair(Type, i*Count)));
}
```

Now, I am trying to extract the character for a particular index. If I had two  elements, I could've used the below one. But with three elements, I am not able to find the solution. Help please :)

```
for(auto &i: my_map)  
  cout << i.second << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Iterating over `my_map` using `auto` gets you key-value pairs. In your case, the key is an `int`, the value is yet another `std::pair`.

`i.second` is the value of the key-value pair, so since it's a `std::pair` too, simply do `i.second.first` to get the value of `Type` and `i.second.second` for `i*Count`.

---

You might want to consider using `const auto &i` here instead, since you don't modify anything and don't intend to, as it seems. Also, `std::endl` flushes the stream buffer, which might be expensive if done in a loop. Just use `'\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

`i.second` will be of type `pair<char, int>&` in your loop.

So in order to access the integer, simply use `cout << i.second.second << endl;`.